# Инициализация свойства при создании объекта ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

Можно ли как-то проинициализировать свойство в компоненте ExtJS при его создании?:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.filter.TextField', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        layout: 'hbox',
        padding: 2,
        config: {
            name: 'undefine',
        },

        constructor: function(config) {
            this.callParent(config);
            this.initConfig(config);
            console.log(config);
        },

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                emptyText: **присвоить значение name сюда**
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: function() {
                    var panel = this.findParentByType('panel');
                    panel.clear();
                }
            },
        ],

        getValue: function() {
            return this.items.items[0].setValue("");
        },

        clear: function() {
            this.items.items[0].setValue("");
        },
    });
```

Хочу чтоб при вызове:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.filter.TextField', {name: 'Username'})
```

происходила установка значения вместо `**присвоить значение name сюда**`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вот такое решение:

```
    Ext.define('Ext.filter.TextField', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            border: false,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch',
            },
            padding: 2,
            config: {
                emptyText: 'undefine',
                name: 'undefine',
            },
            constructor: function(config) {
                this.initConfig(config);
                this.callParent(config);
            },
            initComponent: function() {
                this.items = [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: this.name,
                        emptyText: this.emptyText,
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        iconCls: 'fugue-icon-broom',
                        margin: '0 0 0 2',
                        handler: function() {
                            var panel = this.findParentByType('panel');
                            panel.clear();
                        }
                    },
                ]
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            getValue: function() {
                return this.items.items[0].getValue();
            },
            getName: function() {
                return this.name;
            },
            clear: function() {
                this.items.items[0].setValue("");
            },
        });
```